# Passing POST call values using url_for in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and have been working on an existing app for its login module. It has to be delivered asap. The login credentials validates by **Active Directory** authentication, which is working as expected. I am referring [this flask link](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/Python3_Flask.html#zz-2.7) which says

> url_for('main', page=2): return the internal URL /?page=2. All optional keyword arguments are treated as GET parameters.

My *index* page is loaded from here (working perfectly):

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  error = None
  if request.method == 'POST':
    userName = request.form['username']
    pwd = request.form['password']
    try:
      ldapobject = auth.bind(userName,pwd)
      return redirect(url_for('scheduler'))  ----> NEED TO PASS USER AND PWD TO scheduler function using post here
    except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
      error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again'
  return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

My *scheduler* function:

```
@app.route("/home", methods=['POST'])
def scheduler():
  # some code here
  # WANT TO HAVE USER CREDENTIALS IN THIS FUNCTION FROM login page
return render_template("scheduler.html", scheduler=form)
```

**Problem:** How to pass user's credentials to `scheduler` method as a POST call

Comment: The short answer is: you can't. You cannot pass POST parameters through a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to persist user data between your application pages - you will need to store some session data on user side, e.g. cookies.

`flask-login` module (https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/) can do all the dirty work for you.

In short you need to create `User` class with several required fields and methods (https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#your-user-class) and specify several methods with decorators to load and check users that are being authenticated:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app=app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    return User(username)

@login_manager.request_loader
def load_from_request(request):
    return User.auth_is_valid(request.authorization)
```

After that you can mark any routes that need user credentials with `@login_requied` decorator and access logged in user via `current_user` variable:

```
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
@app.route("/user_needed")
@login_required
def some_function():
    print(current_user)
```